# How to render a twig template in function of the object type in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using a doctrine ['class table inheritance'](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) pattern and have an object referencing my parrent class.
ex:

```
class Pet {
    protected $id;

    protected $age;
}

class Dog extends Pet {
    protected $ownedBones;
}

class Cat extends Pet {
    protected $killedBirds;
}

class Owner {
    private $pets;
}
```

Now I would like twig to select the good template to render my son object in function of their type. So the cats can have a super catly div and my dogs can also have their cool template. 
I tried to do something like that :

```
{%for pet in owner.pets%}
    <div class="pet">
        {{ pet }}
    </div>
{%endfor%}
```

I got a nice :

> Fatal Error: Object of class 'the right type of object' could not be converted to string in ...

So I might be near an answer ?
I'm kind of a Twig newbie so any help would be valued.

Comment: Did you try adding a `__toString()` function to your class? I hope twig will use it automatically. Try with something simple, like `return $this->name;`.

Comment: But, if I do that without putting {% raw %} {% endraw %} ( what could lead to bad stuff ) I'll get "<div class="dog">blabla</div>" In my page, which I don't want either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an abstract method in the class Pet. IE:

```
class Pet
{
    abstract function render();
}
```

Than in your child classes you should implement this method. For example:

```
class Dog extends Pet
{
    public function render()
    {
        return sprintf('<div class="dog">%s</div>', 'blabla');
    }
}
```

In your template, just call render method:

```
{{ pet.render() }}
```

Or else you can always create a `getTemplate()` shared method anche include it in twig: `{% include pet.template %}`

Comment: Yeah that's a solution thanks but, if I wanted to be clean, this kind of method should not be in a class, right ?

Comment: You can always create a `getTemplate()` shared method anche include it in twig: `{% include pet.template %}`

Comment: How, that's better ! Smart idea though :D thanks
edit: Trying now

Comment: I kinda mixed it with a get_class that I put in the parent class and got what I wanted !
Thanks again !

Comment: @StefanoSala, can you incorporate your comment into the answer? Important information is easier to find that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just got another way > do not try to check type, check for properties :

```
{% if pet.ownedBones is defined %}
woot that's a dog
{% else %}
it's somthing else
{% endif %}
```